# How does Thanos know Tony Stark?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

> During the battle of Iron Man and Thanos on Titan Thanos says “Stark?” And then when Iron Man asks "Do you know me?", Thanos says “you are not the only one cursed with the knowledge of everything!”

How does Thanos know Tony Stark? And what is meant by "cursed with the knowledge of everything"?

Comment: I have rolled the question back to my edit so your question has the appropriate tags, capitalisation and not everything is hidden inside of the spoiler block. If you do disagree with my edit though feel free to roll it back.

Comment: He probably wanted to know the name of the guy who nuked his army in the first Avengers movie.

Comment: @JAB I assumed the same, but I think the question is, how did he get to know who nuked his army since pretty much everyone of Thanos' army was dead (believed to be so far) due to that nuclear explosion and the sequels didn't show or hint towards anyone, Earthling or otherwise, giving such information to Thanos or his Children.

Comment: It's probably a combo of Iron Man's actions in the first Avenger's movie and his vision in the second.

Comment: Seers are a cannon thing in marvel I expect thanks has some in his retinue, if not he could have just planted a radio reciever by earth after avengers 1, or had someone listen to Thor's boasts on asguard of his "adventures with the humans"

Comment: Now that this is a Hot Network Question, I've clarified the title to be more explicit. If that's a spoiler, then feel free to change it. It's just that "Iron Man and Thanos" is a terrible question title to be showing on every site's sidebar.

Comment: The very first Avengers movie ends with The Other talking to Thanos about how humans aren't going down easily. Unclear if he knows about Stark specifically at that point, but they clearly have SOME information about the battle of NY.

Comment: Doesn't he have the Soul Stone at this point? That's how I figured he knew who Tony was.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong. The quote should be "You are not the only one cursed with knowledge."

Comment: This is merely speculation, but I remember Iron Man 3 involving a lot of PTSD for Tony after the first Avengers movie. This, along with a vision in the second Avengers movie as Phlegon_of_Tralles mentions, seems to have been interpreted as Thanos being in Tony's head (and vice versa), though Tony clearly didn't grasp what he was experiencing and viewing other than it was cataclysmic

Comment: @aerus you are correct.

Comment: Thanos and The Other had dealings with Loki. Loki got his ass kicked by Stark and company (also got a ton of Thanos' soldiers killed) seems like the identities of the humans who beat him would come up

Comment: Related: [Do Thanos and Stark know each other in Avengers: Infinity War?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88708/49) as well as [What does Thanos mean when he says to Iron Man that he's “not the only one cursed with knowledge”?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88651/49)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Now that Blu-ray disk of *Avengers: Infinity War* has been released, there's a special behind-the-scene video in which Russo Brothers clearly explain that after Loki and Chitauri army lost in *Battle of New York*, Thanos wanted to know the name of the man who foiled his plan and destroyed entire Chitauri fleet in the end. Well, Chitauri intelligence service was at his command and this is how he got to know the name of Stark.

Also, there's another Blu-ray special video in which they play an alternative script:

> Thanos: Stark.
>
> Ironman: How do you know my name?
>
> Thanos: I know your soul. It's much like mine - cursed with knowledge.

This one may imply that Soul Stone gave Thanos an ability to peer into soul of Stark to know everything about him.

But, still, the answer to your question "How does Thanos know Tony Stark?" isn't Soul Stone. Because Thanos already knew Stark before acquiring Soul Stone as I described in the first part of the answer.

Answer (score 18):

One of the powers of the Soul Stone is the ability to learn information by peering into the soul of another. That's how Thanos knows about him. In terms of Tony Stark, the curse of knowledge is a philosophical idea that the more knowledgeable a person is, the more that knowledge can become a burden. The truth can be depressing and being brilliant can be isolating. Thanos was acknowledging that they both share that curse.

Comment: Although we may have to wait till Avengers 4 to get the exact answer, your point is quite well put. +1 for that :)

Answer (score 1):

My takeaway was that he knew this from Loki and the Chitari invasion, or that he gleaned the knowledge from Red Skull. The repeating of the line that Schmidt tells Thanos earlier, "cursed with knowledge", is what I believe Thanos' line is referring to.

Comment: I’m not clear how the Red Skull would have known anything about Tony Stark, given that ol’ Rougeface left earth before Tony was even a twinkle in Howard’s fondue fork.

Answer (score 0):

"Ultron can't tell the difference between saving the world and destroying it. Where do you think he gets that?" - Scarlet Witch, Avengers: Age of the Ultron

Scarlet says this to Cap about Tony. This might be the curse of knowledge that he mentioned. So in this way, Thanos found a similarity between them. Both of them want to save the world and thought wisely (according to their definitions of wise) with Tony using his brain to build Iron Man and fight recklessly and planned to build Ultron, an ultimate AI that could destroy the world, while Thanos wants the universe to be a better, sustainable universe to live in by wiping out half of the inhabitants of the universe.

Thanos could hear about the Avengers who keep ruining his plans all this time that he had to do it all by himself at last. Thanos is smart and got it all planned; he adopted and trained 2 girls to be killing machines. Of course, he would know who are the ones that were messing with him - his enemies.

Also, there's an update on this too.
https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.express.co.uk/entertainment/films/944531/Avengers-Infinity-War-Thanos-Iron-Man-Tony-Stark-link-who-will-die-plot-cast/amp

Comment: “But again... these are my opinions” — cheers, but here on Stack Exchange, we’re [looking for answers, rather than opinions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

I took it to refer to Tony's trip to Chitauri space at the climax of Avengers 1. Tony had already talked about how that trip got Thanos "In his head", which could just mean he can't stop thinking about the experience, as supported by his panic attacks in IM3. But there may be a literal facet to the statement as well.